# Put values from specific tag in a json array into plain array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have `text[]` returning `{1,32}` in my `plv8` and I have to compare what inside of the json below:

```
'{"title":"Televisão em cores"
  , "answers":[{"weight":0, "weight2":1, "title":"Não tem"}
             , {"weight":1, "weight2":2, "title":"1"}
             , {"weight":2, "weight2":4, "title":"2"}
             , {"weight":3, "weight2":8, "title":"3"}
             , {"weight":4, "weight2":16, "title":"4 ou +"}]}'
```

How can I get the all the name `weight2` and transform them into `text[]`? Like `{1,2,4,8,16}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single `json` value `j` in Postgres 9.3:

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT json_array_elements(j->'answers')->>'weight2');
```

Result:

```
array
{1,2,4,8,16}
```

[The manual has more.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html)

Comment: If the OP wants a `text[]` in instead of a `json[]` array then just change `->'weight2'` for `->>'weight2'`

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: Thanks, `->>` fits the question better.